# Associate WP/WooCommerce user with CF7 form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

If using a CF7 form in a "members area" of WP, is there a way to associate who submits the form if the user was originally created through a WooCommmerce purchase?

I know we could just ask for their user name as part of the form, but I'm looking for a better way to solve this where the form automatically pulls in the user ID. We will then push the form submission through a webhook and add automation on the backend based on the form response. It's just this first part I'm looking for help with, and I have not found any good articles on it.

Comment: Accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce gives an example code on how to check if user has bought or not. You can use this at the CF7 hook `wpcf7_submit ` to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

WordPress allows you to query who is currently logged in user for a given requests/form submission with the function [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/).  However, logged-in user credentials are not preserved during a REST api/AJAX call.  CF7 uses the REST api to submit forms and therefore it is not possible to use this function for a CF7 form submission.

You have 2 ways to solve this problem,

.1. Use the [Smart Grid-layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) which fixes many coding issues of the CF7 plugin, one of which is the preservation of user credentials on form submissions, therefore allowing you to use the above mentioned function,

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'get_cf7_user');
function get_cf7_user($form){
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  switch($user_id){
    case 0: //no user logged in.
      break;
    default: //registered user ID.
      $user = wp_get_current_user(); //this is another fn which will get you the user object.
      break;
  }
}
```

.2. alternatively you will need to add the current user's ID into the form as a hidden field to retrieve it once the form is submitted.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036682/3596672) for an example.